# Hiding span under div in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Below is the code for my WP post. I'm trying to hide the span for comment. So that it doesn't appear on the blog post.

```
<div class="blog-stats">
    <span class="clock">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar stats-item"></i>
        <span class="text-center text-light stats-item">February 15, 2020</span>
    </span>
    <span class="comment">
        <i class="fa fa-comment stats-item"></i>
        <span class="text-center text-light stats-item">no comments</span>
    </span>
    <span class="user">
        <i class="fa fa-user stats-item"></i>
        <span class="text-content text-light stats-item">Wayne John</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried a few below and it didn't work.

```
.blog-stats.comment {
    display: none;
}

span .comment {
    display: none;
}

span.comment {
    display: none;
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: with wordpress you will probably need `!important` to make sure it works (only your last selector is correct)

Answer (score 2):

Add below CSS and try :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .blog-stats .comment span{
          display: none !important;
      }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

your CSS code is OKAY!

try putting "!important" besides your style and clear your browser cache. maybe fixed.

Answer (score 0):

please put space between classes like

```
.blog-stats .comment {
    display: none;
}
or
.blog-stats .comment {
   display: none !important;
 }
```

this will work please try

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to use !important try the below version.

```
.blog-stats .comment.comment {
   display: none;
}
```

Note: You can increase the `.comment` class x number of times to get higher precedence.

Example:

```
.blog-stats .comment.comment.comment {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in your css

```css
.blog-stats span.comment{display: none;}
```